# c compilation error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

These are my errors:

> error: static declaration of `doct` follows non-static declaration
>   error: previous declaration of `doct` was here.

And my code is:

```
int doct(int*); /* <- Second error points here */

private int doct(int *a)
  {
    static int a=0; /* First error points here */
    a++;
    *a=a;
    return 0;
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps posting some source code would help?

Comment: Where are the sources ? I can't say much about it.

Comment: Suggestion: Post some code so we know what the errors are referring to. This is no different than us asking "the result is 12, what's the equation?"

Comment: Is this the real code? `private` isn't a keyword I know of in C. Perhaps you mean `static`, which *would* generate the given errors, or perhaps that's a macro.

Comment: with this error I can say, you may forget to give the static in the declaration of doct function and you may give that in the definition.

For Better reply you can post your source code.

Comment: I think this is not your real code.
and also this is not a c code

Comment: @GMan, people often '#define private static' - not something I like but I know it happens. They should learn the language proper rather than adding their own cr*p like that or, $DEITY forbid, '#define begin {'.

Comment: @GMan - this is real code.
@sganesh - in declaration there is no static , same to definition also.

Comment: @ambika: There *must* be a static, otherwise you wouldn't possibly get those errors; I guarantee it. `private` *must* be a macro for `static`, as I mention in the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your prototypes should match your actual functions. Yours do not:

```
int doct(int*);
private int doct (int *a)
```

Either change the prototype to:

```
private int doct(int*);
```

or change the function to:

```
int doct (int *a)
```

You should also bear in mind that `private` is not part of the C language, but people often use it to replace static. This can be made possible by the line:

```
#define private static
```

with the only proviso being that that macro *must* be active wherever you use the `private` name. If it's not working on your prototype, that's probably because it's not defined at that point. My advice would be to ditch `private` altogether and use static (if indeed that's how `private` is defined). People should learn the language, not adopt unnecessary crutches (in my opinion).

Other favourites which I also despise are:

```
#define global extern
#define begin {
#define end }
```

The `private` and `global` are used to mean local to this file and global to all files respectively. The `begin` and `end` are particularly nasty abominations from people who should go back to Pascal where they belong :-)

In addition to that problem, your line:

```
static int a = 0;
```

will actually *hide* the parameter that you're passing into the function (since it has the same name) and:

```
*a = a;
```

will cause an error (since it has a different type). It's rarely a good idea to do that. Rename one of them.

Comment: i make 
int doct(int*);

to


private int doct(int*);

it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I your declaration was in a header, it probably won't work. Is it in a header?

Comment: I'd love to know what does "private" keyword mean in this context, at first :)

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when a function was declared as non-static, then defined static, such as:

```
void foo(void);

static void foo(void) {}
```

Make `static` match on both, either by removing it from both or adding it to both. Make sure you understand what `static` does.

If your function is marked `static`, it is only visible in that translation unit. In your case, your declaration has no static meaning "this function will be available, non-statically.", but then you define it statically.

---

There are other errors. The `a` in your function will hide the `a` in the parameter list. You need to give them different names. `*a = a` won't work because, in that scope, `a` is an integer, not a pointer. Use a descriptive name like `counter` for the integer.

Comment: but in my function there is no static keyword.

Comment: @ambika: You have `private`. `private` is *not* part of the C language, so I can't give you anything else. To generate that error though, `private` must be a macro for `static`. That is: `#define private static`. So put "`private`" in the declaration too, or remove "`private`" from the definition. I would recommend you use `static` instead of `private`, because it's confusing (just look at the responses to it on this question. :] )